# Add numbers based on month

Tags: php, mysql, concrete5

Here I want to get sum total of a person's monthly payment as a report. More than one payment is possible for a month by the same person.

My database looks like:

```
id    member_id              date            amount_paid
12       54(jaison)        2011-10-25          500
13       54(jaison)        2011-10-31          1500
14       55(ram)           2011-03-24           600
15       55(ram)           2011-03-31           400
```

So my problem is in the front end I want to see the data like this:

```
name       jan    feb    mar     apr     may    jun     jul   aug   sep   oct   nov    dec
jaison                                                                    2000
Ram                      1000
```

Comment: whats the question? Or do you just want us to code this for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Group By MemberID and month in the query which is accessing the payment table.

Do you want to know the SQL command to query the DB?

```
SELECT month(date) as mon, member_id, sum(amount_paid) as amount FROM table GROUP BY mon,member_id
```